# Angular material select not working on filtering options

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material, mat-select

I'm using mat select (multiple) along with ngx-mat-select-search to search the items.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-mat-select-search

To display the selected items, I'm using material chips.

Live example: https://ngx-mat-select-search-dy5gaa.stackblitz.io

Stackblitz link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-mat-select-search-dy5gaa

Assume some options are already selected & you search something( it filters options ), then it is clearing the selected options but I'm displaying selected items in the list (just below the select field) that remain unaffected. For chips & list I'm using the same data.

Please let me know how I can avoid disappearing selected items(chips).